$this->request->getSession()->destroy() is not persist in CakePHP 4
I am destroying a session in a Controller method like this:-
public function finallogout()
{
    setcookie('cookie_login', 0);
    $session = $this->request->getSession();
    $session->delete('cookie_login');
    $session->delete('cookie_id');
    $session->destroy();
    return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'catalogue']);
}

However, when I am redirecting to another Controller method, the session is still alive.
function checkLogin() {
    $cookie_login = $this->request->getSession()->read('cookie_login');
    // this gives me $cookie_login as 1
}

What am I doing wrong?

For cookies if you already use cakephp, is much better to use cakephp structure:

This is sample for how to use cookie structure based on cakephp

use Cake\Http\Cookie\Cookie;
use Cake\I18n\FrozenDate;

//create private function to add cookies
private function addCookie(string $name, string $value)
{
    $cookie = (new Cookie($name))
        ->withPath('/')
        ->withValue($value);

    $this->setResponse($this->response->withCookie($cookie));
}

//Create private function to delete cookies by expiring them
private function expireCookie(string $name)
{
    $time = new FrozenDate('2000-1-1');//expire time

    $cookie = (new Cookie($name))
        ->withExpiry($time);

    $this->setResponse($this->response->withCookie($cookie));
}

//sample page with view
public function index()
{
    $this->addCookie('cookie_login', '1');
}

public function welcome()
{
    $cookie_login = $this->request->getCookie('cookie_login');
    $this->set('isLogin', $cookie_login == '1');
}

//sample method without view
public function finallogout()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->expireCookie('cookie_login');
    return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'YourController', 'action' => 'YourAction']);
}

index.php
<?php
echo $this->Html->link('Logout',['controller' => 'Test', 'action' => 'finallogout'])
?>

welcome.php
<h1>Welcome</h1>

 <p>is login: <?= $isLogin == '1' ? h('YES') : h('NO') ?></p>

Cakephp-4 reference
